# Convenience variables via command file

Tags: gdb

[Convenience variables](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html#Convenience-Vars) can be defined like

```
set $i = 0
```

However, when executed [from a file](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/File-Options.html#File-Options):

```
gdb -command COMMANDFILE
```

or [from stdin](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Files.html):

```
gdb <<< "set $i = 0"
```

, gdb prints

> (gdb) A syntax error in expression, near '= 0'.`

Why? How can I use custom variables this way?

Defining such a variable in a [break command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html) or as part of a [user-defined command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html#Define) did not help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just now found the solution. It was my mistake:

```
$i
```

is also bash syntax and thus, from stdin, it has to be escaped in some way.